# DOM created dynamically not showing up in Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

I have a function which basically generates dynamic dom as below

```
const arrMarkup = [];
const getMarkup = () => {
    {
        if(true){
                arrMarkup.push(<Accordion expanded={expanded === cust.name} onChange={handleChange(cust.name)}>
                    <AccordionSummary
                        expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                        aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
                        id="panel1bh-header"
                    >
                        <Typography className={salesEvent.name && classes[salesEvent.name]}></Typography>
                    </AccordionSummary>
                </Accordion>
                )
            })
        })
    }
return <div>{arrMarkup}</div> ;
}
```

Now, i am trying to execute this function is on `useEffect` as below

```
useEffect(() => {
    getMarkup();
}, [cust]);
```

and trying to add in return of JSX as

```
  return (
      <div>
        {arrMarkup}
      </div>
  )
```

but can not see the markup added, however i can see its added in array `arrMarkup`. What's wrong?

Comment: Just curious, it doesn't affect the question, but: Why do you have the extra block in that function?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just a complicated conditional statement which i evaluated as true for mockup.

Comment: No, I mean the block around that. The `if (true)` I understood. But you have a block for the function body (which I get), then another block (which I don't get), and then the `if (true)` and its block...? *Edit:* Actually, the code in the question has unbalanced `}` and `)`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So, that block executes on map of another array. Number of iterations that block execute, the same number of   `Accordion `, i want to be added with the dynamic values as displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React only re-renders your component when its **state** or props change. As far as one can tell from your question, `arrMarkup` isn't either a state member or a prop. (If it *were*, directly modifying it would be against the React rules, because you must not directly modify state or props.)

It's hard to tell you what to do without more information, but you probably want `arrMarkup` to be a state member, for instance (in a functional component using hooks):

```
const [arrMarkup, setArrMarkup] = useState([]);
```

and then to update it appropriately, for instance:

```
setArrMarkup(current => [...current, <NewStuff>goes here</NewStuff>]);
```

Note that I used the callback version of the state setter. That's important when you're updating state based on existing state, since state updates may be asynchronous and can be batched (so the state information you already have can be stale).

---

FWIW, a couple of other observations:

- It's unusual to have the `useEffect` dependency be `cust` (a single object as far as I can tell) and have triggering the effect add an entry to an array that has previous entries for previous values of `cust` which (apparently) you're no longer storing in the component's state anywhere. That just feels very off, without more context.
- You haven't shown the definition of `handleChange`, but `onChange={handleChange(cust.name)}` looks like it's probably incorrect. It **calls** `handleChange`, passing in `cust.name`, and the uses its return value os the change handler. Did you mean `onChange={() => handleChange(cust.name)}`, so that `handleChange` is called when the event occurs?

Comment: Just wandering, what's `current` here? sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @Lara - That's the parameter name I gave for the callback function. You can call it whatever you want. When you pass a state setter a function, React will call that function when it's ready to update the state with the then-current value of the state item. The function above receives that as `current` and uses it to build the new array. In my own code I usually use the name of the state member (`arrMarkup` in this case) but I didn't do that here to try to avoid being confusing. I may have failed there. :-)

Comment: I updated second point of FWIW, i kept `cust` as dependency as its coming from REDUX and takes time, else, the function won;t execute. Is there a better way..I am still learning.

Comment: @Lara - It depends what you want to do, but if there will only ever be one `cust`, you don't need an array. You could do `{cust && <Markup>for cust</Markup>}` when rendering.